# Django Celery Beat - How to pass arguments using the DatabaseScheduler

Tags: django, django-celery, celerybeat

I'm using the "DatabaseScheduler" with the Django Celery Beat, but I can't pass arguments to the function.

The settings:

```
# Django celery
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'django://'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
```

The task:

```
@task()
def some_task(days):
    # Some code
    ...
```

How can I pass the argument "days" using the Django admin? I've created a new "Periodic Task" calling the "some_task". I've tried to pass the argument days with:

```
Arguments: [7]
```

and also tested:

```
Keyword arguments: {"days": 7}
```

Someone can give me a clue on how to pass arguments using the Django admin?

Best Regards,

Comment: Ok. I know what was the problem in my case. I was specifying the  args  like this ['abc','xyz'] whereas it accepts this way ["abc","xyz"]. It accepts double quotes only. In your case though, the argument is an integer. I don't understand why is this failing for you.

Answer (score 8):

The arguments and keyword arguments must use double quotes.

So if you are specifying arguments, it should be like:

```
["aa", "11"]
```

If you are specifying keyword arguments, it should be like this:

```
{"abc": "a", "xyz": "1"}
```